# Trying to install wine 4.0, Unmet dependencies?

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install wine 4.0. I followed all of the instructions on the wine website, but when do:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

It says that

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 wine : Depends: wine1.6
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any suggestions on how to get wine to install? And what is a broken package? Or an unmet dependency?

Comment: You haven't told us your release, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=wine1.6 shows it's available in 'universe' for some releases, but what are you running?

Comment: We don't know which page on "the wine website" you read the instructions from, so we don't know what you did. The error message indicates that you have tried to install wrong-version packages, usually from a wrong-release or non-Ubuntu source. Undo all the preliminary steps you took, and try to return your system to original condition.